Issue with Django and Cross-Origin Request Blocked
i'm having issues with an API i have on docker it works with Django, I can access from other PCs on my network, however everytime i try to log in from any other PC that's not Mine i get the following error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/users/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null). 

Right now my code is like this:
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3001',  
    'http://localhost:3000',  
    'http://127.0.0.1:3001',    
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',  
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True`

I have tried Everything
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

Doesn't work
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3001',
) 

Doesn't work Either
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

Doesn't work
I even tried
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
)

according to the documentation on here

django cross domain security option name is SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#secure-cross-origin-opener-policy

Thanks, i tried that, but it didn't worked Either. I'm still getting CORS errors on other PC.
